# Lógica de consulta para SELECT con BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mariadb

He tenido inconvenientes para formular un *query* que me permita consultar todos los servicios con un rango de fecha y hora.

Caso: Debo mostrar los servicios desde el día anterior hasta el día siguiente, ejemplo: 01/05/2019 15:00:00 hasta 02/05/2019 15:00:00, con un simple BETWEEN me funcionaría, pero al crear el modelo entidad relación definimos dos campos "Fecha" tipo DATE y "Hora" tipo TIME.

Aquí mi BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con [ADDTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) puedes añadir el tiempo a tu fecha.

En este ejemplo se muestran los servicios y su "datetime" que tuvieron lugar entre la fecha actual y hace dos días.

```
SELECT idservicios, ADDTIME(fecha, hora) as dt FROM servicios 
WHERE ADDTIME(fecha, hora) BETWEEN date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes convertir los el campo time a date a la hora de realizar la consulta. Si estas utilizando sql oracle tienes el TO_DATE.
Aquí algunos ejemplos de como puedes utilizarlo:

[TO_DATE function oracle](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta Angago, utilizo MariaDB, buscaré la función más parecida para este gestor de DB.

Answer (score 0):

Para que te resulte más fácil hacer la comparativa, deberías de combinar los campos "Fecha" (DATE) y "Hora" (TIME), y crear un campo de tipo [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) con formato `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Otra alternativa si no quieres cambiar la tabla, sería modificar la consulta que realizas, pero me parece más engorroso. De todas formas si quieres seguir este camino, sube el código con el que haces la consulta para que se te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: Mikel gracias por su respuesta, sí, sería lo ideal cambiar el tipo de campo, con un simple between estaría todo solucionado, pero no podemos. En éste momento estoy planificando la consulta hasta ahora, en realidad es nada, por eso buscaba ayuda por este medio para poder realizar algún código simple que me permita solucionar este inconveniente.